# footnote placement with custom footrule

Tags: footnotes, geometry, footmisc

I've been struggling trying to get my footnotes to fit the way i want them to.
I want the page to have 0.9in border on each side with the header and footer included in the remaining area.
I also want there to be a dashed line `1\baselineskip` beneath the header/above the footnote and `2\baselineskip` of vertical space between the dashed line and the text body.

Can anyone give me a hint on the origin of the problems i'm facing? Thanks in advance!

```
%!TEX TS-program = xetex
%!TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass[
    12pt,
    oneside
]{article}

\usepackage{calc}

\usepackage[
    showframe,
    driver=xetex,
    paper=a4paper,
    top=0.9in,
    bottom=0.9in,
    left=0.9in,
    right=0.9in,
    includeheadfoot,
    headheight=0in,
    headsep=4\baselineskip,
    footskip=0in,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\usepackage[hang,flushmargin,bottom]{footmisc}
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\textcolor{gray!50}{\arabic{footnote}}}

\usepackage{dashrule}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\drule}{
    \renewcommand\makeheadrule{
        \vspace{\baselineskip}
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \color{gray!50}
            \centering
            \hdashrule[-2.5\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{0.7pt}{3pt}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \renewcommand\footnoterule{ 
        \begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
            \color{gray!50}
            \centering
            \hspace{-25pt}\hdashrule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{0.7pt}{3pt}
        \end{minipage}
    }
    \renewcommand\footnotelayout{\onehalfspacing\normalsize\color{gray!50}}
    \setlength{\footnotemargin}{5pt}
    \setlength{\skip\footins}{2\baselineskip}
    \setlength{\footnotesep}{.5\baselineskip}
    \interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
}

\newpagestyle{main}{%
    \drule
    \sethead{\normalsize\color{gray!50}\toptitlemarks\sectiontitle}{}{\normalsize\color{gray!50}\thepage}
}
\newpagestyle{1st_page}{%
    \drule
    \sethead{\normalsize\color{gray!50}\firsttitlemarks\sectiontitle}{}{\normalsize\color{gray!50}\thepage}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{main}
\thispagestyle{1st_page}

\section{1st section}

\lipsum[1] TEST\footnote{test} TEST\footnote{test}
\lipsum[2-3]

\section{2nd section}

\lipsum[1] TEST TEST\footnote{\lipsum[2]} \lipsum[1-3] test\footnote{test} \lipsum \lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\footnoterule` is required to take up 0 vertical space. So I changed your definition to (I think `\parbox` is more lightweight than `minipage`)

```
\renewcommand\footnoterule{%
  \parbox[0pt]{\textwidth}{\color{gray}\centering\hspace{-25pt}\hdashrule[\baselineskip]{\textwidth}{0.7pt}{3pt}}%
\vss}
```

And, please note that `\footnotesep` is the distance of the `\footnoterule` or the previous footnote to the **baseline** of the first line of the footnote. Therefore `0.5\baselineskip` will have no effect. It only does something if it is > `\baselineskip`.